# Animations only appear on client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

there is an animation where the player dances when he presses the button, but this is only visible to the player, other users cannot see it, where am I going wrong?

```
public Animator anim;
[SyncVar] public int animasyonid = 0;
void Start()
{
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();


}
```

void Update()

```
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            animasyonid = 1;
        }


        if (animasyonid == 0)
        {
            anim.Play("Grounded");
        }
        else if (animasyonid == 1)
        {
            anim.Play("Hiphophu");

        }
    }
```